# How to display images on a page when images are stored outside of web root

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-io

When users upload an image, it is stored in the file system but outside of what is publicly reachable.

I am displaying a list of items, and each item has an image associated with it.

How can I display the image when the actual file is stored outside of the wwwroot folder? i.e. it isn't publicly available.

Answer (score 8):

Since the action method is running on the server, it can access any file it has permission to. The file does not need to be within the `wwwroot` folder. You simply need to tell the action method which image to get.

For instance:

```
<img src="/mycontroller/myaction/123">
```

Your action would then look like:

```
public FileResult MyAction(int id)
{
    var dir = "c:\myimages\";
    var path = Path.Combine(dir, id + ".jpg");

    return new FileStreamResult(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open), "image/jpeg");
}
```

Please note that the id is an `int` which will prevent someone from injecting a path to access different files on the drive/share.

Comment: You could also check the incoming filename for invalid characters (including front/back slashes) to avoid the injection issue

Answer (score 3):

You could do this two ways.

Option 1, you could create a Virtual directory which points to this other Directory. This would then mean that you could access the images via another URL. e.g. Create a Virtual Directory called "OtherImages", then your URL would be;

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/otherimages/myimage.jpg
```

Option 2, you could create a simple `HttpHandler` which can load up the image from the absolute path, then output this in the response. Read up on [HttpHandlers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308001) and dynamically generating images.

Comment: true, I forgot about a virtual directory, that would make it more efficient I think.