# Working with images and other files in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, path, imagesource

I know this topic is widely discussed but I can not find even partial answer that works for me.

So I'm working on a `ASP.NET MVC 4` application. For testing purposes I want to use images from my local machine. In my view I have:

```
<div class ="banner-top" style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
    <img src='file:///C|:/Users/My-Pc/Desktop/Images/banner-big-top.png' alt="banner"/>
</div>
```

This is only one of the many attempts I made while trying to display this image. I can see a plain text `banner` and that's all. I tried forward slash, black slash, and I don't remember what else but neither was working and my setup is absolutely simple - the solution is on my local machine, the file is on the local machine. So how can I display this image? Could it be that `MVC 4` itself is preventing the image from showing? I tried everything in FF and Chrome, all the different ways didn't work on both browsers.

Comment: Why don't just use relative paths?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your images are in your project, you would do:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/content/images/banner-big-top")" alt="banner" />
```

Comment: Yeap, as you may see from the OP I use absolute paths and try to figure out how to make them work and if there's a reason not to work

Comment: Why would you want to use absolute paths?  When you deploy this to your server the paths will be different and won't work.

Comment: Try getting rid of the `|` from the `C:/`

Answer (score 0):

Based on the path you listed in the question, it looks like the images are not inside of the website. Why not move them into the website and access them via the website root path?

If moving the files into the website isn't an option, then look at this:

[How to display images on a page when images are stored outside of web root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339113/how-to-display-images-on-a-page-when-images-are-stored-outside-of-web-root)

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that the images are not inside the website. I ask this, because I'm pretty sure in MVC 3 I could display files with absolute path, it's been a long time and I don't save the exact code, but as I wrote - I tried what not and still can not display the image based on an absolute path from the file system.

Comment: In that case check out the link in my edited answer.